# How does a website know my location? Checked with ipleaks and VPN seems to work correctly

Tags: privacy, web-browser, vpn, geolocation

Recently I have been using a VPN to watch a free web series available only in the US -- on a website called https://go90.com. Until a few days ago everything was running smoothly with just Hola VPN. Then for some weird reason the website started to lock me out. I read up a little and saw that when I go to https://ipleak.net/ they could be able to locate me via WebRTC detection and DNS leaks. I went ahead and fixed those so that WebRTC shows no IP on the site and the DNS shows an American address. When I try to go to the go90 website I am still locked out however.

Being at a complete loss I even tried to create a virtual machine with Ubuntu on it, did the same thing so that ipleak shows me as browsing from the US and then for some bizzare reason I can access the main page of the website but clicking on any link takes me to the 'you are not in the US' page. How can the website locate me? What should I do?

If it is helpful I'm currently running Windows 10 and Chrome, though tried similiar things on Vivaldi and Firefox without any effect. Geolocation is set to ask for permission and the website has not asked for it.

Comment: Odds are they are picking up on the fact you're using a known VPN provider, opposed to your actual geo location, and blocking you for that reason. Netflix have recently started doing this.

Comment: @JakGibb Possible, however what is curious is that Netflix seems to work correctly and send me to the US version without any problems. For that reason I believe that something else might be at play here -- I really doubt that this website would do better than Netlix in that regard.

Comment: Do you have [Google Location Services](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142065?hl=en) enabled on chrome?

Comment: @NayCey Smaller sites/businesses often enjoy flexibilities that larger ones do not. That Netflix doesn't block you (yet) is not an indicator of anything.

Answer (score 2):

I did some test right now using a vpn provider and different Tor circuits with a US exit node and i always get back the error page "Sorry. For now...". Probably they are garanting access just for well known US IP subnets.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as [though](https://www.privacytools.io/#fingerprint) some [sort](http://www.radicalresearch.co.uk/lab/hstssupercookies) of [supercookie(s)](http://qz.com/634294/a-short-guide-to-supercookies-whether-youre-being-tracked-and-how-to-opt-out/) were set, to include [browser fingerprinting](https://www.privacytools.io/#fingerprint).